# why my neural network sequential model gets low accuracy ( below than 0.0011)?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I am building a hashtag recommendation model for twitter media posts, which takes tweet text as input and does 300-dimensional word embedding on it and classifies it among 198 hashtags as classes. When I run my model I get lower than 0.0011 accuracy which does not change later! What is wrong in my model?

```
import pickle

import numpy as np

from keras import initializers, regularizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Embedding
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model

package = "2018_pickle"
with open(path1, "rb") as f:
    maxLen, l_h2i, l_w2i = pickle.load(f)
with open(path2, "rb") as f:
    X_train, X_test, X_train_indices, X_test_indices = pickle.load(f)
with open(path3, "rb") as f:
    Y_train, Y_test, Y_train_oh, Y_test_oh = pickle.load(f)
with open(path4, "rb") as f:
    emd_matrix = pickle.load(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    modelname = "model_1"
    train = False
    vocab_size = len(emd_matrix)
    emd_dim = emd_matrix.shape[1]
    if train:
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(
            Embedding(
                vocab_size,
                emd_dim,
                weights=[emd_matrix],
                input_length=maxLen,
                trainable=False,
            )
        )
        model.add(
            LSTM(
                256,
                return_sequences=True,
                activation="relu",
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None),
            )
        )
        model.add(
            LSTM(
                256,
                return_sequences=True,
                activation="relu",
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None),
            )
        )
        model.add(
            LSTM(
                256,
                return_sequences=False,
                activation="relu",
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None),
            )
        )
        model.add(Dense(198, activation="softmax"))
        model.compile(
            loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]
        )
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath, monitor="loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode="min"
        )
        reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(
            monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=2, min_lr=0.000001
        )
        history = model.fit(
            X_train_indices,
            Y_train_oh,
            batch_size=2048,
            epochs=5,
            validation_split=0.1,
            shuffle=True,
            callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr],
        )
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_10 (Embedding)     (None, 54, 300)           22592100  
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_18 (LSTM)               (None, 54, 256)           570368    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, 54, 256)           525312    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_20 (LSTM)               (None, 256)               525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 198)               50886     
=================================================================
Total params: 24,263,978
Trainable params: 1,671,878
Non-trainable params: 22,592,100
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 177278 samples, validate on 19698 samples
Epoch 1/5
177278/177278 [==============================] - 70s 396us/step - loss:     3.3672 - acc: 8.7433e-04 - val_loss: 0.3103 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00001: loss improved from inf to 3.36719, saving model to     ./checkpoints/model_1/lstm-01-3.367-0.001-0.310-0.000.hdf5
Epoch 2/5
177278/177278 [==============================] - 66s 371us/step - loss: 0.1950 - acc: 2.4820e-04 - val_loss: 0.1616 - val_acc: 0.0016

Epoch 00002: loss improved from 3.36719 to 0.19496, saving model to ./checkpoints/model_1/lstm-02-0.195-0.000-0.162-0.002.hdf5
Epoch 3/5
177278/177278 [==============================] - 66s 370us/step - loss: 0.1583 - acc: 0.0011 - val_loss: 0.1570 - val_acc: 0.0016

Epoch 00003: loss improved from 0.19496 to 0.15826, saving model to     ./checkpoints/model_1/lstm-03-0.158-0.001-0.157-0.002.hdf5
Epoch 4/5
177278/177278 [==============================] - 65s 369us/step - loss: 0.1566 - acc: 0.0011 - val_loss: 0.1573 - val_acc: 0.0016

Epoch 00004: loss improved from 0.15826 to 0.15660, saving model to     ./checkpoints/model_1/lstm-04-0.157-0.001-0.157-0.002.hdf5
Epoch 5/5
177278/177278 [==============================] - 66s 374us/step - loss: 0.1561 - acc: 0.0011 - val_loss: 0.1607 - val_acc: 0.0016

Epoch 00005: loss improved from 0.15660 to 0.15610, saving model to     ./checkpoints/model_1/lstm-05-0.156-0.001-0.161-0.002.hdf5
```

Comment: Did you try to train the model for more epochs?

Comment: No, I taught it is not common to get o.oo1 accuracy after 5 epochs  so I didn't go on. Isn't this low accuracy unusual?  @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: You should first train the model properly, 5 epochs might not be enough.

Comment: I trained the model for 100 epochs but the accuracy did not improve from 0,0011 obtained from epoch 3! @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: Then its likely that your labels are not correct, maybe their encoding is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked how many words are covered by your pretrained word embedding? Maybe character or character-ngram embedding would fit better. It would also be interesting to know, what your model predicts now. Does it always predict the same hashtag or random ones?